# send a email with attachment(Problem is the file size is 0k)

Tags: php, excel, email

Dear Friends,
            I have problem with the file attachment, am using email functionality with attachment for my project, i attached the file.xls with that mail, But in mail i cant get that file values, its showing 0k. 
            But that file in local is having some datas, but its not working while run that email functionality, the attachment have 0k size, can anyone help me please...
My code is below....

```
    $filename = "test.xls";
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/to/Documents/"; 
    $file = $path.$filename;

    $to = "example@test.com";
    $subject = 'Repairs List Report';

    $message = "Please find the attachment file for repairs list of Last week...";  //strip_tags($_POST['message']);
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
    //$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 

    $headers = "From: test@example.com\r\nReply-To: example@test.com";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0";

    $message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format. --_1_$boundary Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\" --_2_$boundary Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\" Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit $message --_2_$boundary-- --_1_$boundary Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name=\"$filename\" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment $attachment --_1_$boundary--";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're using? Also, do you mean "the attachment when received is 0 kb"? It's not exactly clear to me.

Comment: please elaborate your question. Either of one can happen. either you receive ur file or don't receive ur file in email. urs is strange case. Please post ur code.

Comment: Try changing the permissions for `$file`. Can PHP read it?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do, is to output $message to see if it does indeed generate a valid MIME-formatted email. We can't be certain, just by looking at your code.. but one thing:

```
$headers = "From: test@example.com\r\nReply-To: example@test.com";
$headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0";
```

should be:

```
$headers = "From: test@example.com\r\nReply-To: example@test.com\r\n";
$headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0";
```

Well you forgot to put all the linebreaks in your message:

```
$body ="This is a multi-part message in MIME format. (preamble)\r\n";
$body.="--_1_$boundary\r\n";
$body.="Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"\r\n";
$body.="--_2_$boundary\r\n";
$body.="Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$body.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$body.="\r\n";
$body.="$message\r\n";
$body.="--_2_$boundary--\r\n";
$body.="--_1_$boundary\r\n";
$body.="Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name=\"$filename\"\r\n";
$body.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$body.="Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n";
$body.="\r\n";
$body.="$attachment\r\n";
$body.="--_1_$boundary--";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

I'm not sure if I missed anything but you can start from this. Lastly you can use a class that I made, [omime](http://sudocode.net/sources/includes/class-omime-php/), which simplifies making mime emails.